# Regarding content slider on mobile screen

Tags: 7, views, javascript, theming

I am trying to make a Drupal 7 desktop site into a responsive one. There is a view of type node listing the node title and image in a grid format on front page. I want that on the mobile screen instead of a grid it just becomes a list of horizontal fields and can be navigated by touch (maybe act as a slider). Any leads how to proceed.

Please shoot out if you need any more info. Would really appreciate any suggestion.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**

[Flex Slider](https://drupal.org/project/flexslider) allows you to build responsive, resizable slideshows. Meaning the slideshows automatically adapt to the size of the browser window or device.

> 1. Touch enabled navigation
> 2. Keyboard navigation
> 3. Configurable slide animations
> 4. Multiple sliders per page

**Option 2:**

[Views Responsive Grid](https://drupal.org/project/views_responsive_grid) provides a views plugin for displaying content in a responsive(mobile friendly) grid layout. Rather than trying to force the standard Views grid display to work for mobile this provides the same functionality